# How to pass arguments to the on_press function from kv language in Python kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have this widget class for the Kivy language,

[image]

it displays the image on the button when it is pressed and released. I need a lot of buttons with different images, but it seems to me not rational to create a new class with new images for each button. How can I transfer the desired images for any button from the kv lang using the same class with this structure?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the methods `on_press` and `on_release` in your Python script
2. Add the following in your kv file

## Snippets - kv

```
MyButton:
    source: 'Images/back_arrow.png' if self.state == 'normal' else 'Images/press_back_arrow.png'
    ...
```